# How can I remove all objects for specific key inside an array after fulfilling the condition?

Tags: javascript

I've got an array(*options*) of objects where each of object also have an array(*answers*) with objects. In those object form *answers* array I've got objects with respondents. Now I'd like to delete respondent form *answers* if all of his answers are *null*.

Array of objects:

```
options [
  {
    optionId: 1,
    answers: [
      {
        respondent: { id: 1, displayName: 'John Doe' },
        answer: null
      },
      {
        respondent: { id: 2, displayName: 'Jane Doe' },
        answer: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    optionId: 2,
    answers: [
      {
        respondent: { id: 1, displayName: 'John Doe' },
        answer: null
      },
      {
        respondent: { id: 2, displayName: 'Jane Doe' },
        answer: true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So basiclly in this case I want to achive to have:

```
options [
      {
        optionId: 1,
        answers: [
          {
            respondent: { id: 2, displayName: 'Jane Doe' },
            answer: true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        optionId: 2,
        answers: [
          {
            respondent: { id: 2, displayName: 'Jane Doe' },
            answer: true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Because all of respondent's 1 answers were null.

First I thought to use forEach() on option array to take those answers, and after this filter but I don't know how to make this condition for one respondent in different arrays.

Comment: please add the wanted result and what you have tried.

Comment: is the order of answers always the same?

Comment: @NinaScholz I've added. Yes, I think order of answers will be the same. Basically I need to delete specific respondent from each answers array IF his all answer are null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could collect all `id` which have a positive answer in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter then all answers with the set.

```js
var options = [{ optionId: 1, answers: [{ respondent: { id: 1, displayName: 'John Doe' }, answer: null }, { respondent: { id: 2, displayName: 'Jane Doe' }, answer: true }] }, { optionId: 2, answers: [{ respondent: { id: 1, displayName: 'John Doe' }, answer: null }, { respondent: { id: 2, displayName: 'Jane Doe' }, answer: true }] }],
    ids = new Set;

options.forEach(({ answers }) =>
    answers.forEach(({ respondent: { id }, answer }) => answer && ids.add(id)));

options.forEach(o =>
    o.answers = o.answers.filter(({ respondent: { id } }) => ids.has(id)));

console.log(options);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```